# Parity of RAID5 systems

Tags: raid, raid-5

I have RAID5 system with 5 disks. How can be obtained information about if a byte is parity or not? Parity bits are moving over disks and i want to catch them but how?

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation specific. So if you want to know how the parity bits are distributed, you must tell us what RAID5 hardward/software you're using.

Note: If the "vendor" is not Linux, then we probably can't help. In Linux, you can have a look at the raid subsystem.